# How to raise the 100 users cap for GCP OAuth?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, single-sign-on, oauth

I've been trying to setup a "Sign in with Google" button on my WordPress website.

In my GCP console I've setup the OAuth consent screen with all the data necessary, I've submitted the app for verification (twice already) and got an email from Google confirming that the app is verified.

Everything worked and users were able to sign up, but only the first 100 users. Now the signup doesn't work anymore and users get a screen saying the app isn't yet verified by Google.

How do I get the 100 users cap raised? I can't get any support from Google.

Can anyone help with this?

In my console it looks like this:

[image: oauth app verified]

Answer (score 0):

As it is explained [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en) the 100 users limit is for apps that hasn't been verified on the OAuth Verification Process.

Starting on January 2020 some scopes changed so verify the scopes you need to ask for and the type of approval they need. Some of the Scopes which changed are the ones related to the identity of the user.

To Verify your app On console go to:
APIs & Services >>OAuth Consent Screen
and follow the process

I share as well the [FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) where you can  solve some additional general doubts